# Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql1)->queryAll() is not returning whole table

Tags: yii

$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('*')->from('states')->queryAll();

above code returns only single first row, while according to documentation it should return all rows.

Comment: How do you explore the $rows?

Comment: i have checked it by print_r($rows); and it returns only single row.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works properly...

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your replies, I have figured out issue, a problem in database. My DB admin just reported it to me.

Comment: Ohh ok, solves this before :P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was caused by a misconfiguration on the OPs site and has nothing to do with Yii.

Answer (score 3):

queryAll() returns an array and u need to iterate in order to get all the records

```
foreach($rows as $row){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: but $rows returns only single row.