# How to write the query in yii,using findAll()

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have the following sql query, how can I write the query in yii  using `findAll()`?

I am not using `CDbCriteria` and for the time being avoiding it.

Using three tables user, category and job_profile.

```
SELECT * 
FROM job_profile
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = job_profile.user_id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = job_profile.category_id
WHERE category_id = 1
  AND experience = 2
  AND key_skills LIKE  '%php%'
```

I have written the following queries but I do not know how to include join:

```
 $results = SearchEmployee::model()->findAll("category_id=:category AND key_skills like 
:skill AND experience=:experience", array(
            'category'=>$category,
            'skill'=>'%'.$skills.'%',
            'experience'=>$experience
            ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$model = JobProfile::model()->with('userrelationname','categoryrelationname')->findAll(array("condition"=>"t.category_id =1 and t.experience =2 and t.key_skills LIKE '%php%'"));
```

You can find relations names in your JobProfile model

Example for relations

There will be source code in your JobProfile Model File like

```
 public function relations(){
    return array(
      'user' => array (self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'id' ),
    )
 }
```

Here is 'user' is relation name...

then in your controller example;

```
foreach($model as $m){
    echo $m['user_id']; // in your job_profile table
    echo $m->user->id;  // in your user table
}
```

Comment: Burhan...what are reffering by relations name ... table name or fields in database

Comment: can u spare some time and join me for a brief chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50940/yii-framework.

Answer (score 2):

you can use queryAll with create command.

```
    $query= " SELECT * 
    FROM job_profile
    INNER JOIN user ON user.id = job_profile.user_id
    INNER JOIN category ON category.id = job_profile.category_id
    WHERE category_id =1
    AND experience =2
    AND key_skills LIKE  '%php%'";

                $result= Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
```

Comment: queryAll returns and Array . You have to use foreach .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717533/yiiapp-db-createcommandsql1-queryall-is-not-returning-whole-table

Comment: @shanavascet...There was a problem with my query and  have changed it.but now its showing error in my view "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: shanavascet...have solved it...my way of displaying data was wrong,corrected it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way:

```
$c = array('join' => 
    array(
        'user' => array(
            'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN',
            'on' => 'user.id = t.user_id'
        ),
        'category' => array(
            'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN',
            'on' => 'category.id = t.category_id'
        ),
    ),
    'condition' => "t.category_id =1 and t.experience =2 and t.key_skills LIKE '%php%'"
);
$results = SearchEmployee::model()->findAll($c);
```