# Writing query in Yii

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have the following query...and want to add few joint additional joint statements in the existing query...posting plane sql query so that it give u idea what I am actually looking for .

```
/* simple sql query */
SELECT * 
FROM job_profile
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = job_profile.user_id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = job_profile.category_id
WHERE category_id =1
AND experience =2
AND key_skills LIKE  '%php%'
LIMIT 0 , 30 
/* simple sql query */
```

I have tried the follwing in yii.And its working fine till now...but I dont know how to add joint statement.

```
  $results = SearchEmployee::model()->findAll("category_id=:category AND key_skills like :skill AND experience=:experience", array(
        'category'=>$category,
        'skill'=>'%'.$skills.'%',
        'experience'=>$experience
        ));
```

I just want to keep the above  statement and just need to add above mentioned joint query in the statement.And I dont want to use adbCriteria for time beign.

Comment: Why would you repost the exact same question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197660/how-to-write-the-query-in-yii-using-findall/23197696#23197696

Answer (score 1):

Good Question . You can use With() by the following way

```
Parent::model()->with(array(
  'childs',
  'childs.grandchilds' => array(
    'select' => false,
    'condition' => 'grandchilds.gender = "MALE"',
  ),
)->findAll(...);
```

**More Eg:**

```
$users=User::model()->with(array(
    'posts'=>array(
        // we don't want to select posts
        'select'=>false,
        // but want to get only users with published posts
        'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
        'condition'=>'posts.published=1',
    ),
))->findAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this one with [relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

the `job_profile` table (I do not know which model you use it in) would need to have 2 relations to `user` and to `category`

Then it would automatically make the join for you, and you would only need to search on the model itself.

Otherwise, if you want to do a complex Select statement, though this is not much MVC like, you can use the [query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand)

or try it simply this way:

`$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('YOUR SELECT STATEMENT')->queryAll();`

Comment: asped...its retreving only one result while doing so...is there anything  wrong in query.

Comment: do you get an array with one result? or simply just 1 object?

Comment: Asped...I am getting array with one result.

Comment: so this simply means that you have either an error in your select, or simply only 1 result in your DB

Comment: ok Asped... I have just corrected my query....can u join me on chat here if u can spare some time... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50940/yii-framework

Comment: its now showing error in my view 'Trying to get property of non-object' till now it was not there

Comment: ok..solved it...Thanks